# questions about the implementation of Complex in c++'s library?

Tags: c++

I find Complex's operator+ in MSVC return **non-const** Complex

```
_TMPLT(_Ty) inline
    _CMPLX(_Ty) operator+(const _Ty& _Left,
        const _CMPLX(_Ty)& _Right)
    {   // add complex to real
    _CMPLX(_Ty) _Tmp(_Left);
    return (_Tmp += _Right);
    }
```

Also, in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_arith3), it is also **non-const**

```
template< class T >
complex<T> operator+( const complex<T>& lhs, const complex<T>& rhs);
(1) 
template< class T >
complex<T> operator+( const complex<T>& lhs, const T& rhs);
(2) 
template< class T >
complex<T> operator+( const T& lhs, const complex<T>& rhs);
(3) 
template< class T >
complex<T> operator-( const complex<T>& lhs, const complex<T>& rhs);
(4) 
template< class T >
complex<T> operator-( const complex<T>& lhs, const T& rhs);
(5) 
template< class T >
complex<T> operator-( const T& lhs, const complex<T>& rhs);
(6) 
template< class T >
complex<T> operator*( const complex<T>& lhs, const complex<T>& rhs);
(7) 
template< class T >
complex<T> operator*( const complex<T>& lhs, const T& rhs);
(8) 
template< class T >
complex<T> operator*( const T& lhs, const complex<T>& rhs);
(9) 
template< class T >
complex<T> operator/( const complex<T>& lhs, const complex<T>& rhs);
(10)    
template< class T >
complex<T> operator/( const complex<T>& lhs, const T& rhs);
(11)    
template< class T >
complex<T> operator/( const T& lhs, const complex<T>& rhs);
```

Then someone maintains that it should be **const**.

However, I just can't think of such a situation which leads to the necessity of non-const.

Can someone show me such a situation? Thanks

Comment: Why *should* it be const? In other words why should `int + int` return `const int`?

Comment: Never post code as screenshots.

Comment: @dandan78 I have edited for screenshots. Thanks!

Comment: You misquoted the 'use const where possible' - the question is "In function arguments with reference types", not in "in function return types"

Comment: @UKMonkey Thanks for your correction. I have deleted this quote

Comment: I would keep your reference to the other question.  It's the reason why you think it should be const; and a very useful tool to help answer the question.  You'll find that getting a reference that says returning a const type much harder!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the question and the answer you linked.

The answer doesn't say anything about the return value of a function. the answer **talks about parameters** passed to a function, and correctly suggests that **parameters** should be passed **as constant references and constant pointers if that function doesn't mutate these parameters**

- Parameters should be passed as const references if that function doesn't mutate them
- function should be declared as `const` if that function does not mutate the object it was called from.

there's is no reason for an `operator + (const T& a , const T& b)` to return const object, doing so may prevent important optimizations.